# Ubuntu 14.04 won't load after update. Mounting /dev or /sys or /proc on /root/dev failed. No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, boot, root

I installed an update about a month ago and could not boot Ubuntu since then. Here is the GRUB menu where I can choose booting options.

[image]

And then the process stops and I see the following messages

Comment: Type `fsck -f /` or `fsck -f /dev/sda5`, then reboot. See if that helps. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: When you boot from a LiveUSB or LiveDVD, and mount the hard drive, are those files there?  Please reply by clicking on edit above at left and add your new data to the original post.

Comment: Hi, @heynnema. I got a message
/bin/sh: fsck: not found

Comment: I put together a quick answer to help do the fsck another way. Once booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD, you'll also want to start the `Disks` app, and look at the `SMART Data & Tests` to review the data and run the tests on your hard disk. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful and solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the fsck command failed at the initramfs prompt, we'll need to check the entire file system.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier (probably /dev/sda5 in your case)
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`